# ResolveAll of certain type with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

On an ASP.NET Core project Startup I have:

```
services.AddScoped<SingleInstanceFactory>(x => y => x.GetRequiredService(y));
services.AddScoped<MultiInstanceFactory>(x => y => x.GetRequiredServices(y));
```

I am trying to use Autofac 4 instead so I tried:

```
builder.Register<SingleInstanceFactory>(y => z => y.Resolve(z)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register<MultiInstanceFactory>(y => z => y.ResolveAll(z)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

However, it seems Autofac does not have a ResolveAll method.

How can I solve this?

**Update**

I also tried to create the following extensions:

```
public static T[] ResolveAll<T>(this IContainer container) {
  return container.Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>().ToArray();
}

public static Object[] ResolveAll(this IContainer container, Type type) {
  Type enumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(type);
  return (Object[])container.ResolveService(new TypedService(enumerable));
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
x.Register<MultiInstanceFactory>(y => z => y.ResolveAll(z)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

But I get the error:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

Not sure what I am missing ... Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve all registered service of T, you can resolve `IEnumerable<T>`

By the way, you are trying to register a delegate which is not required by *Autofac* (see [delegate factory](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html)) and because *Autofac* automatically use composition (see [Composing Relationship Types](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#composing-relationship-types)) you are not required to register anything.

If you want to resolve a `MultiInstanceFactory` or `SingleInstanceFactory` you don't need to register anything in *Autofac*

Comment: With your code I get the error: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: I also added an extension which as an Update to my question but I get the same error as within your code. Any idea why?

Comment: What is `MultiInstanceFactory` ? try `z => new MultiInstanceFactory(y.Resolve ...)`

Comment: MultiInstanceFactory is the following: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/MultiInstanceFactory.cs